# Compute sum of numerical values of an array of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having this input:

```
myArray = [[32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"],
           [654, "ert"]
           [9.4, "a", 1.44, "abc"]];
```

An array of arrays, I want to compute the sum of each sub-array and also ignoring the string values.

I know that for a single array of this type the sum could be computed as:

```
sum = myArray.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).reduce((m, n) => m + n);
```

but when I try to use the same method for a matrix the result is `0`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"but when I try to use the same method for a matrix..."* Show us your attempt. I mean, you surely didn't just use the same code, as the structure of the data is completely different. So...?

Comment: You'er missing a `,` at the end of the second line. (It's not a syntax error because it means the subsequent array will be treated as a property accessor. But it's incorrect. :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to convert the value to a number with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) or take zero for adding.

```js
var array = [[32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"], [654, "ert"], [9.4, "a", 1.44, "abc"]],
    result = array.map(a => a.reduce((s, v) => s + (+v || 0), 0));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` method and inside `filter` to get array of numbers only and then `reduce` to get sum for each array.

```js
const myArray = [
  [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"],
  [654, "ert"],
  [9.4, "a", 1.44, "abc"]
];

const result = myArray.map(arr => {
  return arr
    .filter(Number)
    .reduce((r, e) => r + e)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're now dealing with an array of arrays, you could apply that same code, but it will have to be within an outer `reduce` to loop through the outer array:

```
const sum = myArray.reduce(
    (s, arr) => s + arr.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).reduce((m, n) => m + n),
    0
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const myArray = [
  [32.4, "bla", 1.44, 0.5, 65.8, "abc"],
  [654, "ert"],
  [9.4, "a", 1.44, "abc"]
];

const sum = myArray.reduce((s, arr) =>  s + arr.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).reduce((m, n) => m + n), 0);

console.log(sum);
```